# Insert java byte array in table using Statement

Tags: java, jdbc, hsqldb

Can we insert a java byte array in hsqldb table as blob datatype by using Statement class(without using prepared statement)?

Answer (score 1):

Since you shouldn't insert user data into a SQL statement using string concatenation anyway, why do you care?

Using `PreparedStatement` is the right way to do it.

---

Though, technically, you *could* execute a `SELECT` statement, and insert the data using an updatable `ResultSet`, but I wouldn't recommend it. Inserting a row using a dummy `SELECT` statement is just plain unnecessary overhead.

Or you could build a HSQLDB [Binary Literal](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html#N120D9), but why go through all that work, when you'll get it for free with a `PreparedStatement`?